# Divergence/convergence of an integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (1-e^{ix}) |x|^{-n} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I am told that the following integral converges for $1<n<3$. 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (1-e^{ix}) |x|^{-n} dx
$$
I am a bit baffled. Anyone with a clue or where to start with this in order to evaluate it ?

Comment: With what?  Proving convergence or evaluation?

Comment: Are you sure the interval is $1<n<3$ and not $1<n<2$? Otherwise, do you think of principal values?

Comment: @RonGordon In order to evaluate it.

Comment: mickep I can't be entirely sure but the statement of the problem says $1<n<3$.

Comment: @mickep: $$1-\cos{x} = \sin^2{(x/2)}$$

Comment: @mickep: you are correct.  I take back what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $1-e^{ix}$ is bounded, the "far" side convergence is given by the following:

$$\int^\infty (1-e^{ix})|x|^{-n}dx<2\int^\infty |x|^{-n}dx$$
which converges for $n>1$.

Around zero, you can expand the exponential: $1-e^{ix}\approx -ix+x^2/2$. Now write the improper integral

$$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon (1-e^{ix})|x|^{-n}dx\approx \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon -ix |x|^{-n}dx+ \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon  |x|^{2-n}dx$$
The first term has a zero principal value because the integrand is odd. The second term converges when $2-n>-1$ which is known behaviour of power function around zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now for the value near zero, even though the integrand of the first term is odd, it still blows up at 0. It surely has to be equal to zero, but I am not sure if the argument is valid.

Comment: Yes, for $2<n<3$ the integral is valid only as a Cauchy principal value. In the strictest terms, the integral doesn't converge.

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|$ large
$$
|1-e^{ix}|\,|x|^{-n}\le2\,|x|^{-n}.
$$
The integral converges at $\pm\infty$ if $n>1$.

For $|x|$ small $|1-e^{ix}|\sim|x|$ and the integral converges at $0$ if $n<2$.

What happens if $2\le n<3$? The integral is not convergent at $x=0$. However, for any $r>0$
$$
\int_{|x|>r}(1-e^{ix})\,|x|^{-n}\,dx=\int_{|x|>r}(1-\cos x)\,|x|^{-n}\,dx-i\int_{|x|>r}\sin x\,|x|^{-n}\,dx.
$$
The second integral is equal to $0$ (because $\sin x$ is odd). As for the first one we have $1-\cos x\sim x^2/2$ for $x$ close to $0$, and the integral converges if $n<3$. Thus, if $2\le n<3$ the integral id defined as a principal value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the convergence of the integral is covered fine in the other answers, so just let me give you a **non-rigorous** (depending on your beliefs) way of calculating its value.

With the definition of Fourier transform $\hat f(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ix\xi}f(x)\,dx$ your integral can be seen to be $\hat{f}(0)-\hat{f}(-1)$ (if we agree to split the integral!), where $f(x)=|x|^{-n}$. It is known (see for example the book on classical Fourier analysis by Grafakos) that the Fourier transform of $f$ is
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=2|\xi|^{n-1}\Gamma(1-n)\sin(n\pi/2).
$$
This gives that your integral equals
$$
\hat{f}(0)-\hat{f}(-1)=0-2\Gamma(1-n)\sin(n\pi/2)=-2\Gamma(1-n)\sin(n\pi/2).
$$